# What does it mean to 'know' linux, as opposed to other operating systems?

Tags: linux

I see that this question may appear broad, but it's actually very specific, and should have a specific answer.

I've come across many job postings in the past few years that list 'linux' as a required skill. In my experience as a developer, I've mostly worked out of a Windows operating system, and I'm aware that some of the C++ code I've used is specific to the Windows OS, and I'd assume that many of the shell commands are also specific to Windows.

So what I wonder is: when someone says you should 'know' Linux, what exactly are they referring to, or, in other words, what things specifically should I know about Linux to be able to call it a skill?

Comment: Why was this down-voted? This community is very strange sometimes.

Comment: This is not really on topic, as it is only answerable by the entity asking that you "know Linux".

Comment: You should probably have experience using and programming in Linux. Being very familiar with the command line helps a lot.

Comment: Yeah, really the most specific and accurate answer would be "it depends on what they think it means".

Comment: I would _guess_ and can _only_ guess from experience that they expect you understand how a Linux system works, how the Kernel is loaded, how the filesystem is laid out, and you are comfortable with a Unix command line, probably how services are initialized and managed, the basics of the OS's network stack, etc.

Comment: I would ask for clarification, but in general I would expect them to mean that you are comfortable with bash command line to install packages, create files, run commands, grep searches etc

Comment: Hm, so it's more of a broad question then I thought, but most likely centres on the command shell ,,, so in reality not really a skill at all.

Comment: If you want to get into Linux programming, I'd suggest installing Linux at home, write and compile some short programs, and do as much as you can using the terminal. Some distributions give you GUIs to configure a lot of things, but if you learn the command-line way, it usually works across most distributions.

Comment: Try reading the Linux answers on stack-overflow. When you understand 70% of the commands shown in the answers you are warm. When you can find an answer for 10% of the questions you are hot.

Comment: If this topic is off-topic, which stack community would you suggest I post it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know

- the shell language (and the relevant commands like grep, sed, ...)
- the most popular package-managers/package-formats and how to use them (deb, rpm, ...)
- how and where to configure basic system-wide things (e.g. grub, fstab, ...)
- the basic architecture of linux systems (boot stuff, init system, kernel, userland)
- common concepts (e.g. POSIX, FHS)
- toolchain things (as Hi-Angel already outlined: gcc, clang, gdb and other tools)

I advise against installing things like gentoo for getting into linux. That is quite unrelated and you'll have to deal with a lot of distribution-specific pitfalls (I am a gentoo dev).

Use something which is commonly used, like OpenSUSE or Debian to learn things.

Comment: I disagree on a need to know a package formats, unless one a package manager developer, of course. It is enough to know a few basic commands, like `…update`, `…upgrade`, `…install`, `…remove`, and that's all. Also I disagree on your disagreement about Gentoo. I am wrote it because of own experience: when I tried to install it, I didn't knew how to use terminal, what's the difference between graphical and purely terminal part, what is fstub, grub, and more. Neither I knew terminal utilities. Most of this things I found for the time of Gentoo installing. hasufell, the best learning is a practice

Comment: Gentoo has a lot of design flaws that sneaked in during the decades of development. People who want to set up a linux system and focus on general linux problems will end up dealing with gentoo specific problems instead. And I believe people should know common package formats like deb and rpm (not necessarily the technical side... but the user side as you said yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Linux is part of the *NIX family of Operating Systems. If Linux is a job requiement, then it probably means that your employer uses *NIX OS's and therefore want you to be familiar with how Linux and similiar operating systems work.

The most important thing you need to know is how NOT to use a gui, but rather a text-based console.

Answer (score 1):

That does mean you ought to know at least basic GNU/Linux commands, and understand at least abstractly how are things work there (i.e. what is kernel, what is X server/client, what is window manager, what is file rights, users, groups). Actually it is easy to learn, just try to install some linux distro from a source code. E.g. [Gentoo](https://www.gentoo.org/). It would teach you how things are works there.

Also, since you are looking for a developer job, you ought to have a little 
coding experience in GNU/Linux. As I recall what could wonder you as you came from Windows®, it is the `fork()` function, and a missing need to tackle with `wchar`s — because there is everything in UTF8. Also in GNU/Linux you may find something like offline MSDN — so called manual. If you install a few developer *man* packages, you may find there an offline description for many system and C-specific functions.

A few more tips: α) The `/proc/` filesystem. You may find there directories which are actually PIDs of running processes. You may find there many useful info. E.g. the `/proc/somePID/exe` is a symbolic link to the executable file of the running process. β) Almost every GNU/Linux distro contain many tools which would be useful for programming. `gcc` *(compiler)*, `nm` *(list symbols from object files)*, `md5sum`, `hexdump`, `gdb` *(debugger)*, `objdump`. γ) Everything is a file. That does mean that e.g. if you wanted to create an image of a usbstick, you don't even need a specilized tools, you may just find it's file in the `/dev/` directory, and with `dd` utility, which just copying a file content, write it to a file. δ) Everything you installed you can next launch from a terminal, that is, you don't need to seek for executable. An executable file usually installed somewhere in `/usr/bin/`, but anyway, it would always be in your $PATH variable.

Comment: Ah, also you may find interesting, that in file names is allowed almost every symbol. Even the `*`, even the backslash *(not the slash!)*, even the newline character! The only two symbols disallowed is the directory separator — slash `/` — and the symbol with code zero, because zero usually does mean end of a string.